# File upload to s3 not working after setting visibility to public

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

Trying to configure Laravel to upload to my aws s3 bucket. It is working fine until I change visibility to public. Then it seems to work or at least it does not show any error but nothing gets uploaded to aws.

Here is the part in my register controller where I am uploading a profile picture

```
       if($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
            $file = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $file->storeAs('avatars/' . $user->id, $filename, 's3');

            $user->update([
                'avatar' => $filename,
            ]);
        }
```

And here is the configuration for s3 in filesystems.php

```
        's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        'throw' => false,
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Without the  `'visibility' => 'public',` it is working fine but as soon as I add it nothing gets uploaded anymore.

Comment: Are you sure removing `'visibility' => 'public'` works? Did you check the log files inside `storage/logs` for errors?

Comment: On your controller, can you try using `storePubliclyAs`. So try using `$file->storePubliclyAs('avatars/' . $user->id, $filename, 's3');`

Comment: @aceraven777 have tried storePubliclyAs and it's the same issue, have tried without the visibility and it does save the file without it. Nothing shows up in the log file

Comment: maybe is the settings of your s3 bucket, do you use ACLs enabled? Or your bucket permission maybe you Blocked all access.

Comment: @aceraven777 acls is disabled and blocked access is off

Comment: Did you try using `storePubliclyAs` but REMOVE the `'visibility' => 'public'` in  `filesystems.php`

Comment: @aceraven777 Just tried but it's the same issue :/

Comment: Can you try creating the bucket again and follow the instruction here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQ0gi9YHuek

Comment: @aceraven777 Have tried it and it is still not working. Followed the entire tutorial actually building a new app but does not work.

Answer (score 8):

I had this before, you need to Edit **Object Ownership to ACLs enabled**. By default it is disabled which means that all objects. on the bucket is yours as a private, but ACLs let you choose if you won't object to being public or private.

if you will create a new s3 bucket, in Object Ownership enabled ACLs.
or if you have already created a bucket go to permissions and edit Object Ownership to enable ACLs.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was enabling public access to my bucket and adding bucket policy that makes the files in question publicly readable. You can read the [official docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html).

Also, make sure to remove the "visibility" => "public" line from Laravel as this prevents the upload from taking place.